# iOS image loader effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using "SVProgressHUD" for loader. When I want to load an image from url I am using async process to load the image in background. After completing the download I am updating the UI. And for that time span I am using a placeholder on the imageview and a loader with "Please wait..". But I want to use a loader like "Instagram". That means, when an image is loading from online it loads a blurry image of the original image and upon downloading the image , the blurry image show the original image.

Can any one please suggest me how can I do this?

Comment: do you own the server and control the images and server handling?

Comment: Do you have at least access to a "thumbnail" version of your image that can be easily (I mean fast) downloaded?

Answer (score 4):

The stuff you are talking about is **Progressive JPEG**.

> Progressive JPEG (PJPEG) is an image format that stores multiple,
>   individual “scans” of a photo, each with an increasing level of
>   detail. When put together, the scans create a full-quality image. The
>   first scan gives a very low-quality representation of the image, and
>   each following scan further increases the level of detail and quality.
>   When images are downloaded using PJPEG, we can render the image as
>   soon as we have the first scan. As later scans come through, we update
>   the image and re-render it at higher and higher quality.

So, you have to make images loadable in this modern progressive format.You can follow a approach where every image before saving on server just convert it into appropriate progressive format.There are several tools avaiable for different type of server. E.g [jpegtran](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/)

To check whether image is progressive or not you can use this [tool](http://highloadtools.com/progressivejpeg) or [tool2](http://techslides.com/demos/progressive-test.html).You can search for online tool a lot of tool is available.

Now for **iOS**

You can follow this [tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/ios/posts/loading-images-ios-faster-with-progressive-jpegs)

Some library
[Concorde](https://github.com/contentful-labs/Concorde)
[DFImageManager](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager)

Comment: [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke) also supports progressive JPEG starting with version 7. So does [PINRemoteImage](https://github.com/pinterest/PINRemoteImage) and some other libs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in control of the hosting of the images you can host lower resolution images and make 2 fetches, one for the lower resolution, and one for the higher. If you make the lower resolution image significantly smaller in file size the fetch for it will finish before the fetch for the full image, and you populate the `UIImageView` with this image until such a time as you can replace it.

Purely example code would look like this:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()

let lowResOperation = NSBlockOperation {
    guard let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://myhost.org/low-res-image")!),
        image = UIImage(data: imageData) else { return }

    if imageView.image == nil {
        imageView.image = image
    }
}

let highResOperation = NSBlockOperation {
    guard let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://myhost.org/high-res-image")!),
        image = UIImage(data: imageData) else { return }

    imageView.image = image
}

let backgroundQueue = NSOperationQueue()
backgroundQueue.addOperations([lowResOperation, highResOperation], waitUntilFinished: true)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. But unfortunately the code is not working.

Comment: It's example code, you need to apply the concept yourself.